# How to install latest version on cifs-utils (v6.10) on Ubuntu 18?

Tags: 18.04, samba, cifs

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I can see there are some fixes added to cifs-utils package in both 6.9 and 6.10. But when I try install in Ubuntu 18.04 only version 6.8 is installed. Can someone help me installing 6.10 (the latest verions) on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

The repositories for your current ubuntu version don't have the newer packages available.

What you could try to do if you really need that package into your Ubuntu install is to download the [package](https://pkgs.org/download/cifs-utils) from the newer versions, or even get the [source](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/groovy/cifs-utils) and build by yourself. Keep in mind that the former might not work due to dependencies, while the former would probably work but would also be a more involved process.

My recommendation would be to actually upgrade your ubuntu install to the latest LTS (20.04) if possible, since it'd bring you the latest package without much worries.

Comment: I checked the Ubuntu 20.04 also. It has only cifs-utils 6.9 not the latest.

Comment: 6.10 will be available on [groovy gorilla](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/cifs-utils)